# How to play a partially looping sound in python

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game with pygame and I have a waiting music for the lobby. I want this to play until the game starts. It would play a beginning part and then loop the rest infinitely. I have gone back and forth on what I should use to make the game. At first I was using unity with FMOD. This is what it was like in FMOD and what I am aiming to do in python[image]

Answer (score 0):

well, you can set a countdown until the beginning part is completed and then it will start looping the middle part like this:

```
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

songBeginningLength = 15
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 1000)

mixer.music.load('BeginningPart.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(1)  # loop 1
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            songBeginningLength -= 1
            if songBeginningLength == 0:  # check if countdown is done
                mixer.music.load('MiddlePart.wav')
                pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)  # loop forever

    clock.tick(60)
```